# Trying to understand how to compare orders of growth of two functions

Tags: polynomials, logarithms

I recently came upon the problem asking which functions can be considered $O(x^2)$.

One of the choices was $x(lnx)^2$, which I understood to be bound as $\lim{x\to\infty}$ by a polynomial of degree two.

The question I have is, for what $n$ is $x(lnx)^n$ no longer $O(x^2)$

Answer (score 0):

${{xln(x)^n}\over x^2}={{ln(x)^n}\over x}$. Write $u={1\over x}$, $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{{ln(x)^n}\over x}=lim_{u\rightarrow +\infty}(-1)^nu{ln(u)^n}=+/-\infty$ so $xln(x)^n$ is not $O(x^2)$.